# How do I prevent deletion of a pointer returned by a member function?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

Consider the sample code below. The class `Data` is used to store an array of data: for simplicity, I chose to use a `vector<char>` as data member. However, these data must be processed by an external routine, which requires a pointer to the first element of the array and, of course, the length of this array: for this reason, I have also implemented the functions `get_data()` and `get_length()`.

```
class Data
{
public:
    Data(const char* sourcePtr, int sourceLength) : _data(sourcePtr, sourcePtr+sourceLength) { ; }

    const char* get_data() const { return &_data.front(); }
    int get_length() const { return _data.size(); }

    void print() const
    {
        vector<char>::const_iterator it;
        for(it = _data.begin(); it != _data.end(); ++it)
            cout << *it;
    }

private:
    vector<char> _data;
};
```

Now consider the following code sample, which uses the class `Data`.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* a = new char[4];
    a[0] = 'b';
    a[1] = 'y';
    a[2] = 't';
    a[3] = 'e';

    Data myData(a,4);
    delete[] a;

    myData.print();
    cout << endl;

    const char* aPtr = myData.get_data();

    // The following statement frees the memory allocated
    // for the data member of the class Data.
    delete[] aPtr;

    return 0;
}
```

The above statement `delete[] aPtr` frees the memory allocated for the data member of the class `Data`. As a consequence, when the `myData` object is deallocated automatically, the content of the `vector<char>` has already been deallocated manually, and obviously an error **SIGABRT** occurs.

How to ensure that the compiler signals the statement `delete[] aPtr` as an error? How should you modify the class `Data` to achieve this goal?

Comment: You can't. It is one of the many problems with returning raw pointers.

Comment: Basically, as soon as you give a raw pointer to the outside world, you are at their mercy. Why do you need to give one out anyway? There's a reason `vector` goes to the trouble of exposing (abstract) iterators.

Comment: you can wrap with a smart pointer, that's a about it (someone could always call `operator->` explicit on it, though)

Comment: You should always make clear in the documentation who owns the pointer that you return. If someone ignores that documentation they get what they deserve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way to deal with this is to make sure that it is clear who is the "owner" of a pointer. In my C++ days, if a pointer was returned by a function, the function's name should start with "Create" rather than "Get". Later, we usually returned smart pointers, in such a scenario.

It is in fact not at all hard to write C++ where you never need to delete any pointer explicitly, but rather store all of them in a smart pointer that will delete the pointee when it gets destroyed itself.

Answer (score 4):

Stop using "naked" `new` and `delete` operations, wrap the `new` in an RAII type and do not use `delete` unless you're writing a destructor of an RAII type.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> a{ new char[4] };
a[0] = 'b';
a[1] = 'y';
a[2] = 't';
a[3] = 'e';

Data myData(std::move(a),4);
```

This code means that ownership of the array is clearly given to the smart pointer, and then clearly transferred to the `Data` object.  Attempting to `delete` the array will not compile.

This doesn't prevent users later doing `delete[] aPtr` but if you get into the habit of **never** using `delete` except in the destructor of an RAII type, then it becomes *glaringly* obvious when someone introduces a bug by using `delete` somewhere they shouldn't, because they don't own the memory.

Stop fiddling about with bare pointers.  If users of your code won't stop doing so then let them learn the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  `new` and `delete` don't track who owns the pointer.  That's your job.

What you can do instead is make a copy of the data the pointer points to.  Then it doesn't matter what the caller does with its array.  You have your own copy, and assuming you're not doing something braindead like exposing it to anyone who wants it, it's safe.

Or, check out `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.  :P  They're the new hotness as far as memory management is concerned; when you use a smart pointer, memory very nearly manages itself.

Comment: not sure what you mean, it's an array in this case, so making a copy and returning it would require an allocation and passing ownership of the allocated copy. but i withdrew my comment after you mentioned smart pointers.

Comment: (and i guess you withdrew yours after i withdrew mine :D)

Comment: @StephenLin: What i mean is, `char x[5]; Data mydata(x, 5);` would cause problems if the `Data` object assumed that was its pointer now and should be deleted on destruction.

Comment: yeah, but that's not his problem AFAICT--he's copying the data from `x` into a vector in `mydata`, so that's ok; his problem is that he wants to return a pointer to the data in `mydata` (that he still owns) and prevent it from being deleted. he can copy it before and returning a copy of that, but then the caller must free it.

Answer (score 1):

Write good documentation. It's not your job to prevent other programmers from doing stupid things.

Comment: "It's not your job to prevent other programmers from doing stupid things". Never mind other programmers - It's *definitely* your job to stop YOURSELF from doing stupid things. Returning a smart pointer instead of a raw one tells every programmer (without looking at the docs) that they should not manually delete the returned object.

Comment: @Roddy - I don't see anything in the question that suggests that the goal is shared ownership. Absent that, a smart pointer only adds overhead.

Comment: I think the "shared ownership" is kind of implicit and unavoidable when you have functions returning pointers (or, indeed, references). If the OP's worried about the caller `delete`ing the returned pointer in error, he probably will also be concerned about the caller trying to dereference the pointer after the pointed objects  lifetime. There is overhead, yes : but often the benefits in fewer bugs outweigh them.

Comment: @Roddy - no, shared ownership is a design decision. Returning a shared pointer means that whatever it points to **can outlive** the object that returned it. In this case, where the pointer currently points to data stored in a `std::vector`, that requires a major redesign.

Comment: Agreed. We're bogged in the details a bit, and smart pointers (shared or otherwise) are just one "technical" approach to the problem. Returning an iterator, or a reference could be others. But, I still believe that returning raw pointers and relying on documenting what NOT to do with them should be a policy of last resort.

Comment: Upvoted, just because returning a smart pointer here is obvious nonsense (it's a pointer to a vector's data!)